# Pass Parameter into RMySQL dbSendQuery

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm having difficulties passing a value into dbSendQuery.
Below is my code:

Parameter:

```
date_param <- '2014_02_02'
```

Query:

```
  pull <- dbSendQuery(test_db, "select distinct product_id, group 
                                 from test_table 
                                 where date between date_sub(",date_param,", interval 1 year) and ",date_param," ;")

pulled_data <- fetch(pull, n=-1)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in is(object, Cl) : 
  internal error in RS_DBI_getResultSet: could not find resultSet in connection
```

Is the issue with my syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a very old question, so I am hopeful that you have already resolved your issue.  As @MrFlick suggested, `paste` builds a string and allows you to pass it as a single parameter.  However, in so doing, you have to do some semantics to make sure dates are quoted properly.  Since I do not have the table you are discussing (or information about what data is in it), I will build a simple query to show what is happening.

At present, what you are likely submitting to the database is something akin to:

```
date_param <- "2014_02_02"

## currently submitting
paste0("select distinct product_id, group from test_table  where date between  date_sub(", 
  date_param, ", interval 1 year)  and ", date_param, " ;")  

#> [1] "select distinct product_id, group from test_table  where date between  date_sub(2014_02_02, interval 1 year)  and 2014_02_02 ;"


## analogous query
paste0("select  date_sub(", date_param, ", interval 1 year) as start , ", date_param, 
  " as end;")
#> [1] "select  date_sub(2014_02_02, interval 1 year) as start , 2014_02_02 as end;"


## need to quote the dates
paste0("select  date_sub('", date_param, "', interval 1 year) as start , '", 
  date_param, "' as end;")
#> [1] "select  date_sub('2014_02_02', interval 1 year) as start , '2014_02_02' as end;"
```

If you copy and paste the last query into a SQL Editor, it should work the way that you expect (notice the quotes around the dates).

The benefit of using `paste` (or `paste0` - no separator) is that you can capture exactly the query that is being sent and test it yourself in a SQL Editor.  The downside is the irritating quoting behavior and risk to SQL Injection (as well as a lack of type safety).  The *better* solution is to use variable substitution, which differs a bit based on the implementation (RMySQL and RMariaDB use `?`, RPostgreSQL and RPostgres use `$1`,`$2`,`$3`,etc.).  See the [`DBI Spec`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/spec.html#_description_46) for more info - you can also sometimes get a performance gain by preparing the query ahead-of-time.

Note also that the `RMySQL` package is being phased out - `RMariaDB` is compatible with both MySQL and MariaDB and is where future development looks to be taking place.  (From my exploration, it looks like the `RMySQL` package does not have great support for prepared queries like this)

```
library(RMariaDB)

date_param <- "2014_02_02"

conn <- dbConnect(MariaDB(), ...)

query <- "select date_sub(?, interval 1 year) as start, date(?) as end;"

rs <- dbSendQuery(conn, query, list(date_param, date_param))
dbFetch(rs)
#>        start        end
#> 1 2013-02-02 2014-02-02
dbClearResult(rs)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine your SQL statement into one string. Right now you are passing the pieces as separate parameters. Try using `paste()` to make your stateent.

```
pull <- dbSendQuery(test_db, paste("select distinct product_id, group 
                             from test_table 
                             where date between date_sub(",date_param,", interval 1 year) and ",date_param," ;"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried that but it returned zero results. There definitely is data for that specified range.